# Sorting floating Pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, std

We have:

```
 private void function(ptr* data, const int size_of_data){
       std::sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data), floatcomparer);
```

Is this actually possible? Is there another way? Cause I get here an `error: no instance of overloaded function ""std::begin" matches the argument types are: (float *).`
I know that we need the size for a fast sorting algorithm like std uses and ptr* doesn't deliver an included size. But shouldn’t there be a way cause I know how big the array is I'm pointing on?

Comment: public is not allowed in function definition.

Comment: true that, i'll edit

Comment: Neither is private. Please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

Comment: You can if you pass an array by reference to function template.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort(arr, arr+ size, std::greater<float>());
```

where you can use pass `float arr` in this form

```
func(float[],int sz){...}
```

With this comparator you can sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature is wrong and you're calling `std::sort` incorrectly, you want something more like:

```
void function(float* data, std::size_t size_of_data) {
    std::sort(data, data + size_of_size, std::less<float>());
}
```